# SQL Database connectivity fails in eclipse

Tags: sql-server, database, eclipse, jdbc

Error Message:

Creating Connection to DB: 
Make SQL Connection:

```
sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'.
ClientConnectionId:3978d1be-ff31-4ab5-9ce1-89719d44a54f
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:254)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:84)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2908)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2234)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at DatabaseConnectivity.getDBConnection(DatabaseConnectivity.java:65)
    at DatabaseConnectivity.main(DatabaseConnectivity.java:74)
```

What is the solution for this problem.?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There's no actual code here, so it's difficult or impossible to tell what could be wrong. Please edit that into your question.

Answer (score 1):

> Login failed for the user sa

Check the if the user exists in the server with the right permissions and check the password you're using.

Comment: and also... user `sa` is disabled by default